# How to update information of the data of column in the table matching the certain text?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a condition where i need to update the only matched case of the data in the table. 
For an example
I have a #test table

Sample data are

```
Firstname Lastname
ABCDEF    GHIJKL
BFGABCF   FGYUTY
CDFSERABC VVVVVV
```

I need an update query which match the 'ABC' in the #test table and update that 'ABC' with 'XYZ'.

Resulting data must be

```
Firstname Lastname
XYZDEF    GHIJKL
BFGXYZF   FGYUTY
CDFSERXYZ VVVVVV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy : [**REPLACE (string_expression,string_pattern,string_replacement)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE FirstLastName
    ([Firstname] varchar(9), [Lastname] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO FirstLastName
    ([Firstname], [Lastname])
VALUES
    ('ABCDEF', 'GHIJKL'),
    ('BFGABCF', 'FGYUTY'),
    ('CDFSERABC', 'VVVVVV')
;


select * from FirstLastName
```

--- now update the table

```
update FirstLastName 
set Firstname = replace (Firstname,'ABC', 'XYZ')
-- optional (else it will do an upadte to entire table) !!
--where somecondition
```

[SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf303/2)

Answer (score 1):

use the T-SQL replace function

Check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f08a/2

Comment: You are doing a select as opposed to OP wants an UPDATE :-)